# Firefox miscalculating box model on pseudo element

Tags: css

the following HTML:

```
<div>foo<br/>bar</div>
```

and the following CSS:

```
div {
    border-left: 30px solid #995D2F;
    position: relative;
}
div::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: -30px;
    top: 0px;
    border: 3px solid #EBBD00;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
}
```

According to Firefox Dev-tool's "Boxmodel" it renders the pseudo element with a width/height of 25px and a border-width of 2px.

Why?

My Firefox version is 35.0.1. It is a Firefox portable if that makes any difference.

http://jsfiddle.net/neg3f9yn/

[image: Firefox Zoom Level end Devtools]

**Edit:** If I add `box-sizing: border-box;` to the pseudo element and change width/height to 30px it looks right for me: http://jsfiddle.net/neg3f9yn/1/
I'd still be interested in an explanation what is happening there.

Comment: You may have zoomed out accidentally. It says 3px for me.

Comment: Just double checked, Firefox shows I am at 100%, but when I zoom in it actually looks better....

Comment: Weird. Can you upload a screenshot of what it looks like at 100%, together with the dev tools?